# ubuntu Selenium temp directory location

Tags: ubuntu, selenium

Where is the location of the selenium temp profile directory?

I am trying to debug a script.

the script stops before it can run:

```
driver.quit()
```

hence it takes up more and more memory.

so I need to manually find and flush the folder first as the HDD is now full.

Comment: Are you using the GUI or just trying to do this in Terminal? Or are you trying to do this from within the test itself?

Comment: GUI or terminal either ok.

Comment: Dropped a GUI answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KillerSnail,

In Java this will find the current directory and print it out.

```
public class TempDirExample {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("OS current temporary directory is "
          + System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
      }
}
```

To find the tmp directory via the GUI

> First launch the file manager by clicking on "Places" in the top menu and selecting "Home Folder". From there click on "File System" on the left part and that will take you to the / directory, from there you'll see /tmp, which you can then browse to.

To find the tmp directory via the terminal

> Type **nautilus /tmp** in terminal it will open /tmp

Hope you find this helpful.